# Blender cycles bakong awfully

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I am baking the leather of a seat in cycles. I bake it and it looks like this.[image]

But in rendered view with the material it looks like this.[image]

This has never happened before. Does it have to do with my mesh? It has a lot of vertices.

these are the uv unwraps.

[image]

There are no extra faces. I did remove doubles.

The random black things on the uv map  are wrong.

**also it won't let me comment to anything even though i can edit i cant respond to comments**

Comment: What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: What does your UVs look like? Are you sure there are no duplicated faces in that mesh, or duplicated objects? Are you using the same UVs for the texture in the bottom image as the bake?

Comment: Repardeimaj please contact the SE team about your two accounts. (when I did they said it would be better if you did.) You can use the [contact form](https://blender.stackexchange.com/contact) then choose "I need to merge user profiles."